# Using Chef's Cookbook recipes to dynamically override an attribute

Tags: ruby, cassandra, ubuntu-12.04, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm trying to setup a new cookbook for Cassandra, and on `cassandra.yaml` file which has the follow comments about optimal settings:

```
# For workloads with more data than can fit in memory, Cassandra's
# bottleneck will be reads that need to fetch data from
# disk. "concurrent_reads" should be set to (16 * number_of_drives) in
# order to allow the operations to enqueue low enough in the stack
# that the OS and drives can reorder them.
#
# On the other hand, since writes are almost never IO bound, the ideal
# number of "concurrent_writes" is dependent on the number of cores in
# your system; (8 * number_of_cores) is a good rule of thumb.
```

However, there's no way to determine the `numbers of cores` or `numbers of disk drives` predefined in the attributes because the deployed servers could have different hardware settings.

Is it possible to dynamically override the attributes with the deployed hardware settings?  I read the [Opscode doc](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_execute.html) and I don't think it has a way to capture the output from 
`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l`

I was thinking about something like this:

**cookbook-cassandra/recipes/default.rb**

```
cores = command "cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l"
node.default["cassandra"]["concurrent_reads"] = cores*8
node.default["cassandra"]["concurrent_writes"] = cores*8
```

**cookbook-cassandra/attributes/default.rb**

```
default[:cassandra] = {
  ...
  # determined by 8 * number of cores
  :concurrent_reads => 16,
  :concurrent_writes => 16,
  ..
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can capture `stdout` in Chef with `mixlib-shellout` (documentation here: https://github.com/opscode/mixlib-shellout).

In your example, you could do something like:

```
cc = Mixlib::ShellOut.new("cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l")
cores = cc.run_command.stdout.to_i # runs it, gets stdout, converts to integer
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found a way to do this in recipes, but I haven't deployed it yet to any box to verify it yet.

```
num_cores = Integer(`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l`)
if ( num_cores > 8 && num_cores != 0 ) # sanity check
  node.default["cassandra"]["concurrent_reads"] = (8 * num_cores)
  node.default["cassandra"]["concurrent_writes"] = (8 * num_cores)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using chef 11 so this may not be available on previous versions, but there's a `node['cpu']` attribute with info about the cpus, cores and etc.

```
chef > x = nodes.show 'nodename.domain'; true
=> true
chef > x['cpu']['total']
=> 16
```

And you can use it on your recipes. That's how the Nginx cookbook does it.